# Pycharm : locating pipenv executable

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, pipenv

**I am trying to use pipenv in PyCharm with Python 3.8 but cannot locate the pipenv executable.**

Current situation :

I have installed Python 3.8.2 on a Debian platform (actually LMDE 3), where Python 2.7 and 3.5 were already installed globally (in `/usr/bin`). I want to use Python 3.8 for development and leave th other two untouched. Python 3.8 is hence now installed in `/usr/local/bin`.
I have used the `which` command to locate the binaries and confirm the aforementioned locations.

I have installed `pip` and `pipenv` in Python 3.8 and left untouched Python 2.7 and 3.5.
The `python` command still refers to Python 2.7 and `python3` to Python 3.5. The command `python3.8` refers to Python 3.8.2.

Similarly :

- `which pip` points to nowhere (pip not installed by default with Python 2.7).
- `which pip3` points to /usr/bin/pip3
- `which pip3.8` points to /usr/bin/pip3.8

Pipenv is installed for Python 3.5 and 3.8.2 as it is my development environment. 
I located the python module in `/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/pyenv.py`
(similar path for Python 3.5)

The command `pipenv` does not work as such. What works is `python3.8 -m pipenv <something>` or `python3.5 -m pipenv <something>`.

However, running the same 'which' command for pipenv (or pipenv3, pipenv3.5, pipenv3.8) returns nothing.

I have also found pip files (binaries ?) in `/home/user_name/.local/bin/` : pip, pip3, pip3.5, pip3.8, pipenv, pipenv-resolver . I have no idea what these are for.

Can anybody explain me what is this mess and how I configure PyCharm correctly ?

Answer (score 7):

This does not answer the OP, but for those using Windows 10 who end up here based on the question title:

For a per-user installation of python 3.9, I found the executable here:

`C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pipenv.exe`

Comment: Thanks that helped me out to get pycharm working with pipenv! Of course I first forgot to `pip install pipenv` ...

Answer (score 5):

After verifying that path was correct by using `type pipenv`. I was able to get it to work by clicking the file path selector in the pycharm configuration setup and selecting the path that was already selected `/home/user_name/.local/bin/pipenv`. After manually selecting the already selected file location, the message went away.

Answer (score 0):

[image showing pipenv path in pycharm][1]/Users/user_name/Library/Python/3.11/bin/pipenv

I found the corresponding pipenv executable on above path
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRzUN.png